# How to define a decision variable with an index with depends on an other index of the same decision variable?

Tags: scheduling, job-scheduling

Imagine there is a machine environment with 5 production stages and each of these stages contains a different number of identical machines (so called flexible flow shop).

Now there are jobs which have to be scheduled. All jobs have to start at stage 1 and processed on the stages in the production Environment from stage 1 to stage 5. On every stage only one machine have to work on one Job. Additional every job only needs maximal one machine per stage to work on (some jobs may skip stage 4 because they dont need to be prepared there).

I have 2 constraints with the decision variable x[j][i][f].

The first says, that each job can processed by max. one machine per stage.
The second says, that each machine can only process max. one job at the same time.

Now my problem is, to define the decision variable because the number of machines f depends on the stage i. I.e.:

- stage i = 1: m[1] = 3 machines
- stage i = 2: m[2] = 2 machines
- ... and so on.

So the upper bound (i.e. m[i]) of the sum of the both constraints C5 & C6 depends on the value of i.

```
     // Indices
     int Nmax = ...; 
    range N = 1..Nmax; // jobs j in N

     int Mmax = ...;
    range M = 1..Mmax; // stages i in M
        {int} m[M]  = [{1,2,3},{1,2},{1,2,3,4,5},{1},{1,2,3}]; // Numbers of machines per stage
        {int} F = union(i in M) m[i];

       //decision variables:
         dvar int+ S[N][M]; // starting time of job j in stage i
         dvar int+ E[N]; // earliness of job j
         dvar int+ T[N]; // tardiness of job j.
         dvar boolean x[N][M][F]; // decision variable

      // objective function
      dexpr float Costs = sum(j in N) (E[j] + T[j]);
      minimize Costs

     subject to{
     C5: forall (j in N, i in M) sum(f in m[i])  x[j][i][f] <= 1;
     C6: forall(i in M, f in m[i]) sum(j in N)   x[j][i][f] <= 1;           
     }
```

Fortunately, I don't have an error message anymore. But it seems, that CPLEX don't understand that the number of machines belongs to the stages.

For example:
As solution for the decision variable x[j][i][f] i got seven 5x5-matrices. So one matrice for each job, which firstly seems to be correct. 
But all values of the matrices are zero. Moreover, cplex scheduled the jobs at stage 2 in a way, that there should be at least 3 parallel machines, but there are only 2...

Comment: I think your question is not very clear. What is decision variable and why is number of machines per stage fixed when it was in the question title?

Comment: I changed the describtion and added some Information. Hopefully now my question is clear

Comment: Hi, why do not you try cpoptimizer within opl Cplex ? See examples at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplexamples/topics/opl_cp_examples_scheduling.html#descriptiveTopic1204630323463__section1204631732401 regards

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks i will try it.
I've  already checked the examples but didn't thought they fit with my case. Because there are several machines but only at one stage and not at a couple of stages. And like I said, my problem is, to tell cplex that there are 3 machines at stage 1, 2 machines at stage 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that

```
{int} m[M]  = [{1,2,3},{1,2},{1,2,3,4,5},{1},{1,2,3}];
```

means that in the first stage machines 1,2,3 are available, in the second stage machines 1,2 are available, etc.

Since you use `F` and not `m[i]` as index for `x` this means, that you have too many variables (too many options) in stages that don't have all machines active. This can be fixed by forcing the variable that correspond to unavailable machines to zero (untested code):

```
forall (stage in M)
  forall (job in N)
    forall (machine in F : !(machine in m[stage]))
      x[job][machine][stage] == 0;
```

This allows only the machines specified in `m` to process any jobs in a stage. With that your constraints C5 and C6 should be sufficient: they only involve machines that exist and variables corresponding to other machines are 0.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
unfortunately it doesn't work.
The solution for the starting times is:

      S[Jobs][Stages] = [[2 5 8 12 16]
                                  [4 7 11 14 18]
                                  [4 6 10 18 22]
                               [13 15 19 24 24]
                               [12 16 19 25 25]
                               [10 14 18 26 30]
                              [17 20 23 27 31]];
You can see, that on stage 2 job 1, job 2 and job 3 are processed during the same time period. Also job 4, job 5 and job 6.
So I would need more than 2 machines in parellel...

Comment: Furthermore all values of the seven x[j][i][f]-matrizes are still zero.

Comment: Well, the problem you report now seems unrelated to constraints C5 and C6 since the S variables do not appear in this constraint. My best guess is that something is wrong in the linking of x and S variables. If some S is non-zero then some corresponding x should be non-zero as well, or not? So it seems you are lacking a constraint that enforces that.